# overriding const function declaration as key in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, constants

Hi and thank you in advance

I am wondering if there is a way to override a const function?

example:

```
const n = function(){alert('bob')};
```

so is it possible to reference the function something like this:

```
n.function = function(){alert('for apples')};
```

What I did here doesn't work.

Thanks
again

Comment: why do you use `const` for changing content? btw, the above works, but need to call with `n.function();`.

Comment: The 'proposed' code shown is "equivalent" to, eg. `const n = {}; n.some_property = some_value` .. `const` says nothing about the *mutability* of the named object; just that the name ("n") always evaluate to the *same* object/value (and thus always 'reflects' the changes *to* the named object) ..

Comment: Why doesn't it work? You need to call it as `n.function()`, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't override the value of a `const`-declared variable. Just use `let` instead.

```js
let n = function() { alert('bob'); };

n();

n = function() { alert('for apples'); };

n();
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

> The value of a constant cannot change through re-assignment, and it
>   can't be redeclared.

Since functions are objects though you can add properties to them. Therefore, `n.function = function(){alert('for apples')};` will work since you are appending a property called `function` to your `n` object. That means that you can execute that function by doing `n.function()` as Nina Scholz suggested in the comments.